# How do I detect the position of a substance with just a wire perimeter

Tags: proximity-sensor

I need to be able to tell the position of a material preferably a magnet with a very low profile  perimeter  like wire.

Comment: This question has not nearly enough content or specifics to be answerable

Comment: what is the range of motion of the substance? ... how accurate should the system be?

Comment: https://patents.google.com/patent/US8532822B2/en

Comment: @Rohan I need to be able to determine the position of a part on a flat sphere. I can attach pretty much any substance to the part that will be moving around inside the sphere. It needs to be extremely thin and pretty two dimensional. I was thinking something like a magnet, And wire perimeter but I’m not sure if anything like that exists

Comment: @jsotola Picture a 2 inch Circle with 1/ quarter inch circle inside it. I need to know where the quarter inch circle is at all times. Not on the Y axis . The Y axis is irrelevant

Comment: @Bruce Abbott That looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: @what-hasThis-world-come-to that description belongs in the question ... right now, your question is vague

Comment: What is a "flat sphere"?